# How to iterate over a list with a n-sized window and operate on matched and unmatched set of elements?

Tags: python, list, iterator, sliding-window

I have two list of elements, and I want to match within a window, and things that does not fit/match into a window. For example,

```
reference_window_list = ["a b c", "p q r", "b c d"]
input_elements = "a z p a b c p e p q r" # ....
```

I should be able to call my_func() from a loop like,

```
my_func('a') // First element of the list
my_func('z') // Second element of the list
my_func('p') // Third element of the list
my_func('a b c') // Forth group of elements that matched with reference_window
my_func('p')
....
my_func('p q r')
...
```

I thought, I could loop through 3 elements-window

```
for i, (previ, currenti, nexti) in enumerate(zip(word_list, word_list[1:], word_list[2:])):
    find_match(reference_window, previ, currenti, nexti)
```

But that does NOT solve my problem. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: why is the third call `my_func(p)` and not `my_func(c)`? Please carify the logic. Also, please fix your code as you're not using defined variables and avoid mixing stuff like "..." or "and so on" that make the syntax invalid, use comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex for that. The regex would be in the form `\b(a b c|p q r|b c d|\w)\b` where the first part is build from the list of potential matches and then defaults to a single character `\w` (or more if you want using `\w+`)

```
import re

reference_window_list = ["a b c", "p q r", "b c d"]
input_elements = "a z p a b c p e p q r"

reg = r'\b(%s|\w)\b' % '|'.join(reference_window_list)

for e in re.finditer(reg, input_elements):
    print(e.group()) # used print here as dummy function
```

output:

```
a
z
p
a b c
p
e
p q r
```